# How can I configure the data present in HBase caputure to Apache Kafka

Tags: hbase, apache-kafka

Now presently I am working based on HBase and Kafka.

**My requirement is:**
Suppose if I have some data present in HBase Database. Now I need to capture the database to Kafka. Here my HBase database acts like a producer and when ever I have created anything in the database/producer it automatically captures to Kafka consumer.

I have followed many links but I have not got the exact solution. Please give me suggestions and provide some links based on the requirement. If You want any extra information ping me.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the database as producer, you might want to look into Kafka Connect.

It allows to ingest data from external sources reliably into Kafka.

- https://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#connect
- http://docs.confluent.io/3.0.0/connect/index.html